# Set An Action For a Button in HTML

Tags: html, forms, css, submit

I'm a Little Beginner in HTML/CSS ! Sorry if Question is Ridiculous !
I Have a Form (e.g Contact Form) , I Want When User Pressed Submit , The Stuff Send for Me , What Should I Do ?! Thanks.

Comment: Boy, you need to learn a lot, HTML alone won't send you some stuff, you will have to learn server side scripting like ASP.NET or PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try same like this code...
and set action and method for `<FORM>` tag which transfer to that action page...
and over there you can get the data using the `<input>` tag's name and the method which was defined in `<FORM>` tag. (to get data you can use `$_POST['bat_year']`)

```
<form id="abc" name="abc" action="xyz.php" method="POST">
    <select class="comb" id="bat_year" name="bat_year">
        <option value="0" selected>WAFT Sports Rounders World Ranking Batting 2014</option>
        <option value="Year 5">Year 5</option>
        <option value="Year 6">Year 6</option>
        <option value="Year 7">Year 7</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter name" id="user_name" name="user_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay 10p">   
</form>
```